# Windows Task Manager equivalent for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac

My MacBook seems to be really slow these days, no matter what I do. On Windows I had so many choices to figure out what's taking memory, CPU cycles and what not and take action appropriately.

Wondering if there is an equivalent alternative for Mac OS X for what Task Manager is for Windows?

Comment: As an aside, as the title of your question may bring people here: Opt-Cmd-Esc to get the Force Quit dialog.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[Activity Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_Monitor). It's included with OS X. Just look in your *Applications/Utilities* folder or use Spotlight to find and open it.

[image]

Comment: I wish they made this as part of the "Apple" menu. Pretty basic stuff that can save some people some vent fan heat ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

[Activity Monitor](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1342) found in [Applications](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2476)/[Utilities](http://www.freemacblog.com/exploring-the-utilities-folder-on-your-mac/) folder.

O'Reilly Mac Dev Centre has a [good run down on how to "read it"](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mac/2005/10/04/activity-monitor.html).  And [Peek-a-boo](http://www.clarkwood.com/peekaboo/) is a good way to show you how processes connect to one another.

Although if you really want to know what your system's up to, I'd recommend [iStat pro](http://islayer.com/apps/istatpro/).

[image: istat pro]

Comment: I run iStatPro but that doesn't give me the details on what process is juicing up my CPU cycles.

Comment: no, but is shows you what processes are running.

Answer (score 7):

As others have answered, Activity Monitor in `/Applications/Utilities/` is the most direct equivalent to the Windows Task Manager, but there are other options..

I mainly use [iStat Menus](http://www.islayer.com/apps/istatmenus/) to work out which application is using up all the CPU time..

Instead of having to launch Activity Monitor (which takes a few seconds to start), I just click the little CPU menu bar item, and it lists the current top processes:

[image: iStat Menus CPU menu]

You can also use the "top" command instead of Activity Montior (it's quicker to launch also). Just run the `top` command in a terminal:

[image: the top command]

I have an alias `ltop` which launches top, ordered by CPU usage, with a few flags to reduce it's CPU usage (reduces it's accuracy with regards to memory usage, but uses about 2% CPU instead of about 10-12% by default):

```
alias ltop='top -F -R -t -o cpu'
```

Comment: or alternate is `htop`

Comment: When I try this in 2016 with Mac OS Sierra I get the error `invalid option or syntax: -t`

Answer (score 4):

One thing that will help when using Activity Monitor is to add columns of information (exactly the same as Process Explorer). Right-click on the process columns and you can add significant additional info:

[image]

Another important piece of information to look at in activity monitor is your paging:

[image]

What this shows is how much hard disk page swaps have occurred and how much swap memory is physically written to disk. If you see active page ins/outs, then an application is forcing swapping.

Comment: seems like a big missing piece of functionality compared to Process Explorer is the paren/child subprocess relationship among the processes. If I'm not mistaken `Activity Monitor` just lists them all out in a flat fashion with no notion of the hierarchy that may or may not exist between the various processes.

Answer (score 2):

[Tasks Explorer](https://github.com/astavonin/Tasks-Explorer), which is close to Activity Monitor, although has some features which Activity Monitor does not have (process environment, used shared libraries, opened files, exported symbols).

I also find useful **htop** utility from *nix-world (available in macports).

Answer (score 1):

Also, interesting to note that you have a shortcut ( that took me a year to remember ) to quick access that:

```
command+option+esc
```

Super handy ( as Task Manager in Windows is super super handy )

Answer (score 0):

You can check out "Mac Helpmate" to tidy up your OS.

Answer (score 0):

A powerful utility (CLI) is process explorer from mac, available [here](http://newosxbook.com/index.php?page=downloads). It emulates Linux top with Mac OS X and iOS specific options, and is also grep-able.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [brew](https://brew.sh/). Check `htop` it's a terminal-based monitor system

1. `brew install htop`
2. `htop`