# When I try to turn off my Mac, the Finder menu appears

Tags: macos, finder

Whenever I try to turn off my Mac, this Finder menu appears on top:

[image: Finder menu]

It doesn't go away even when I try to Force Quit this application using Command+Option+Escape.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong with it?

Comment: Is it causing a problem, or are you just curious about why it appears?

Comment: AlSo, making people wait 30 seconds to view a photo is stupid, use something like www.imgur.com instead of RapidShare.

Comment: +1 Won't check your image like this, sorry.

Comment: @JRobert it is obviously causing problem . How an earth will i shut down my mac while this finder window is showing on top. When i try to force quit finder only 'Relaunch' option is available.

Comment: please note the "edit" link underneath your question. Please add more details then. (All of us have Finder running while we shut down our Macs, so that menu is not your problem and there's really no need to stop Finder *before* shutting down. So, there must be some more details you can add? What does [activity monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/24862/windows-task-manager-equivalent-for-mac-os-x/24863#24863) show you? Is it the only application showing in the Force Quit dialog?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: Nothing is wrong with your Mac.

The Finder is the default application used on the Mac OS and Mac OS X operating systems that is responsible for the overall user-management of files, disks, network volumes and the launching of other applications.

As a result you cannot remove it entirely. Think of it as being similar to the Start Bar or Explorer on Windows. You wouldn't want to close explorer.exe on Windows, as it would leave the GUI of your machine unusable.

Comment: When this finder toolbar appears on top i am unable to shut down my mac. When i try to force quit finder only 'Relaunch' option is available. Its been a while tht I m facing this strange problem.

Comment: As Scorchin said, you can't normally quit Finder, only relaunch it. It's not a problem, it's a *feature* of OS X ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Quit-Finder-Mac-os-X/step3/Enter-the-command/) a guide to adding a 'Quit'-button to the Finder menu.

It's basically:

1. In Terminal: `defaults write com.apple.finder QuitMenuItem -bool yes`
2. Relaunch Finder

However, I can't imagine that not being able to quit Finder makes your Mac un-shotdownable; are you sure you don't have anything else running in the background?

Comment: I doubt one can quit Finder if there's nothing else running. (On my Macs Finder relaunches automatically if no other foreground application is running.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming normal operation, You always see Finder because it is the "last guy still standing" after all of the other apps have been killed off to get ready for shutdown.  You don't need to kill it; the system will do that.

Edit: If you actually need to kill Finder, try Shift-Clicking the Apple menu.  Since Finder is then the front-most application, the menu will offer to Force-quit Finder. I'm not sure killing the Finder will fix whatever is blocking your shutdown process, but it's worth a try.

Comment: When this finder toolbar appears on top i am unable to shut down my mac. When i try to force quit Finder only 'Relaunch' option is available. Any idea how can i shutdown my mac in this situation !